# When I move the robot in the tutorials, I find that Gazebo GUI dispalys blank

Tags: gazebo, plugin

When  I add the Diff_drive plugin into the building_robot.sdf and save the file, then I use 'ign gazebo building_robot.sdf'  to start Gazebo. However,The Gazebo GUI shows nothing.
The Diff_drive plugin is shown below. Appreciate any help!
[image]

[image]

Comment: what version of gazebo? if you run gazebo with the `-v 4` arg you'll get more verbose output and may see what the errors are.

Comment: My gazebo version 9.19.0.

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the text